# Sort a dictionary contained in an array

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, dictionary

Hello I have a dictionary contained in an array. Something like this:

```
var array = [[String: Any]] ()
```

After executing a certain code, the array is filled with the following example data:

```
array = [["Date": "Sat-16-May", "sched": ["8:00 - 8:30", "8:30 - 9:00", "09:00 - 09:30" ]]
["Date": "Thu-14-May", "sched": ["8:00 - 8:30", "8:30 - 9:00", "09:00 - 09:30"]]
["Date": "Fri-15-May", "sched": ["8:00 - 8:30", "8:30 - 9:00", "09:00 - 09:30"]]
["Date": "Mon-11-May", "sched": ["8:00 - 8:30", "8:30 - 9:00", "09:00 - 09:30"]]
["Date": "Sun-10-May", "sched": ["8:00 - 8:30", "8:30 - 9:00", "09:00 - 09:30"]]
["Date": "Wed-13-May", "sched": ["8:00 - 8:30", "8:30 - 9:00", "09:00 - 09:30"]]
["Date": "Sat-09-May", "sched": ["8:00 - 8:30", "8:30 - 9:00", "09:00 - 09:30"]]
```

]

What I need is to be able to sort them by day of the week. Because he always prints it to me in a different order

I have found solutions to sort dictionaries, but not to sort dictionaries contained in an array. How can I access the dictionary key (Date) to order them according to that data?

Thank you :)

Comment: `var dict = [[String: Any]] ()`, that's an array of dictionaries. Naming it `dict` is MISLEADING. So you sort an array where each object is a dictionary.  I notice that you have 2 date formats: `"Sat-May 16"`& `"Thu-14-May"`, why?

Comment: you're right it has been corrected. It was a drafting error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Note

First of all, the example data has a few inconsistencies in the date formatting, as mentioned by @Larme.  This answer assumes that the example data was intended as below, and adds "AM":

```swift
array = [
    ["Date": "Sat-16-May", "sched": ["08:00 AM - 08:30 AM", "08:30 AM - 09:00 AM", "09:00 AM - 09:30 AM"]],
    ["Date": "Thu-14-May", "sched": ["08:00 AM - 08:30 AM", "08:30 AM - 09:00 AM", "09:00 AM - 09:30 AM"]],
    ["Date": "Fri-15-May", "sched": ["08:00 AM - 08:30 AM", "08:30 AM - 09:00 AM", "09:00 AM - 09:30 AM"]],
    ["Date": "Mon-11-May", "sched": ["08:00 AM - 08:30 AM", "08:30 AM - 09:00 AM", "09:00 AM - 09:30 AM"]],
    ["Date": "Sun-10-May", "sched": ["08:00 AM - 08:30 AM", "08:30 AM - 09:00 AM", "09:00 AM - 09:30 AM"]],
    ["Date": "Wed-13-May", "sched": ["08:00 AM - 08:30 AM", "08:30 AM - 09:00 AM", "09:00 AM - 09:30 AM"]],
    ["Date": "Sat-09-May", "sched": ["08:00 AM - 08:30 AM", "08:30 AM - 09:00 AM", "09:00 AM - 09:30 AM"]]
]
```

### Best Practice

Your example data indicates that you are storing durations for dates.  The best way to sort these is by using `[Date: [DateInterval]]`.  When you want to display these dates and durations as strings, you can use a `DateFormatter` for the `Date`'s and a `DateIntervalFormatter` for the `DateInterval`'s.  This data can be stored as a `Dictionary` and sorted into an `Array` of tuples with the keys and values, `[(key: Date, value: [DateInterval])]`.

```swift
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "eee-dd-MMM"

let intervalFormatter = DateIntervalFormatter()
intervalFormatter.dateStyle = .none
intervalFormatter.timeStyle = .short

var newDict = [Date: [DateInterval]]()
```

**The sorted Array:**

```swift
let arrayOfTuples = newDict.sorted { (left, right) -> Bool in
    left.key > right.key
}
```

Any time you need to display one of these dates or intervals, you can simply use:

```swift
dateFormatter.string(from: aDate) // replace aDate
intervalFormatter.string(from: aDateInterval) // replace aDateInterval
```

If you want to use your example data as a literal for testing or otherwise, you can convert it to `[Date: [DateInterval]]` using this code:

```swift
let disposableFormatter = DateFormatter()
disposableFormatter.dateFormat = "eee-dd-MMMhh:mm a"
    
array.forEach { dictionaryPiece in
    let dateString = dictionaryPiece["Date"] as! String
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)!
    let sched = dictionaryPiece["sched"] as! [String]
    newDict[date] =
        sched.map { (stringInterval: String) -> DateInterval in
            let start = disposableFormatter.date(from: dateString + stringInterval.components(separatedBy: " - ")[0])!
            let end = disposableFormatter.date(from: dateString + stringInterval.components(separatedBy: " - ")[1])!
            return DateInterval(start: start, end: end)
        }
}
```

### The Other Way

Finally, if you simply want to sort your data exactly as it is, you can just use `Array.sort(by areInIncreasingOrder: (Element, Element) throws -> Bool)`, as implemented below.

```swift
var array = [[String: Any]] ()

array = [
    ["Date": "Sat-16-May", "sched": ["08:00 AM - 08:30 AM", "08:30 AM - 09:00 AM", "09:00 AM - 09:30 AM"]],
    ["Date": "Thu-14-May", "sched": ["08:00 AM - 08:30 AM", "08:30 AM - 09:00 AM", "09:00 AM - 09:30 AM"]],
    ["Date": "Fri-15-May", "sched": ["08:00 AM - 08:30 AM", "08:30 AM - 09:00 AM", "09:00 AM - 09:30 AM"]],
    ["Date": "Mon-11-May", "sched": ["08:00 AM - 08:30 AM", "08:30 AM - 09:00 AM", "09:00 AM - 09:30 AM"]],
    ["Date": "Sun-10-May", "sched": ["08:00 AM - 08:30 AM", "08:30 AM - 09:00 AM", "09:00 AM - 09:30 AM"]],
    ["Date": "Wed-13-May", "sched": ["08:00 AM - 08:30 AM", "08:30 AM - 09:00 AM", "09:00 AM - 09:30 AM"]],
    ["Date": "Sat-09-May", "sched": ["08:00 AM - 08:30 AM", "08:30 AM - 09:00 AM", "09:00 AM - 09:30 AM"]]
]

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "eee-dd-MMM"

array.sort { (left, right) -> Bool in
    formatter.date(from: left["Date"] as! String)! > formatter.date(from: right["Date"] as! String)!
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I have corrected my code saving directly as dates and not as strings. It has been easier to order my arrangement and now everything flows better than before. +1

Comment: Glad I could help.  Good to hear.

Answer (score 0):

Taking your data structure as-is, you can sort your array(!) like this

```swift
var arr = [[String: Any]] ()
arr.sort { (dict1, dict2) -> Bool in
    let date1 = dict1["Date"] as? String ?? ""
    let date2 = dict2["Date"] as? String ?? ""
    return date1 < date2
}
```

That said, if at all possible, you should avoid stringly typed APIs that rely on `[String: Any]` dictionaries and the resulting casting and optional checking hassle.

Comment: Sat-09-may vs Fri-15-May are you sure about your comparison ?